# Wait for condition in Enzyme and Jest (eventual consistency, assert with timeout)

Tags: reactjs, microservices, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple test:

```
import React from 'react';
import GenericButton from 'components/buttons/GenericButton';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';

describe('Generic Button', () => {
    test('Button action called when clicked', () => {
        var clicked = false;
        const component = shallow(
            <GenericButton action={() => {
                clicked = true;
            }}
            id="testComponent"/>
        );

        component.find('testComponent').first().simulate('click');
        expect(clicked).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

However this will fail as the action is done eventually,

If i set the assertion to happen eventually (using setTimeout for example) it will work

however it would be better if i do something of the following before the assert (found this on examples using jasmine)

```
        waitsFor(() => {
            return clicked;
        }, "the value to change", 1000);
```

What is the equivalent call for enzyme/jest?

---

Edit: Content of component

```
render() {
    return <Button id={this.props.id}
                   key={this.props.id}
                   onClick={() => this.props.action()}
                   bsStyle={this.props.style}>
               {this.props.text}
           </Button>;
}
```

(Button is a 3rd party library component)

Comment: In a unit you should never need this. Can you post the code you want to test?

Comment: i am ensuring in the above case that my button's action is done when it is clicked.

Comment: Sure, but the only thing that happens when ` component.find('testComponent').first().simulate('click');` runs, is to find the `onClick` property and call it, so there is no way that this is not working in every test run. As there is no real DOM involved, this is just a function call. So the only use case for `waitsFor` is when you run an acceptance in a real or headless browser. But this is not the case when you use Jest.

Comment: yet by doing this i am ensuring that the action passed is actually mapped to the onClick property. If not jest what would be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a click handler was added correctly pass a spy into your comment, simulate the click and check that the spy was called. Doing this there is no need to use `waitsFor`.

```
import React from 'react';
import GenericButton from 'components/buttons/GenericButton';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';

describe('Generic Button', () = > {
  test('Button action called when clicked', () = > {
    const action = jest.fn();
    const component = shallow(
      <GenericButton action={action}
            id="testComponent"/>
    );
    component.find('Button').first().simulate('click');
    expect(action).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: This still fails due to timing. By the time the expect is called, the action will not have been called yet. (I assume this is due to the asynchronous nature of the call)

Comment: Can you please post the code where the action is called in the component, cause there is no async involved here, this is all sync as no real browser in running. `simulate` just takes the property `onClick` from the component and calls the function.

Comment: added it.  to the question

Comment: turns out it's not in fact an issue with asynchrony but rather the call not being made (as i had added a custom implemnetation of waitFor using setTimeout but the test was actually ending before the call was done)

Comment: As I said don't use any `setTimeOut` stuff in your test, this is all synchronous code (functions that call functions and so on), there is no way that the last line of the test is running before the the click action was called in the Button component.

Comment: in that case is your example given cause my prop is not called onClick but rather action ?

Comment: I have no idea why this is not working for you. Can you check if `component.find('Button').first().prop('onClick')();` works. Please also check that `component.find('Button').first()` is the expected button. Have a look on how to debug Jest: https://liusy182.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/jest-how-do-you-debug-it/

Comment: the solution was to in fact use component.find('Button') rather than the identifier. Thank you :)